# How to pass parameter when executing a node.js script?

Tags: node.js, parameters

I wish to send some parameters when running a node script, using for instance

> node myscript.js

from the terminal, so it can be read as below:

```
const fs = require('fs');

console.log(myParameter);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to call as many arguments as you want, like:

```
node myscript.js arg1 arg2 arg3
```

And you recover them like:

```
console.log(process.argv[2]);
```